# Why poll() returns immediately on regular files and blocks on fifo?

Tags: c++, posix, polling, file-descriptor

I checked this code several times and cannot understand why does poll() return immediately?

Here file is opened for read and should wait for event. How to make it wait for input?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


using namespace std;

ssize_t read_out_to_the_end(int fd){
   char chunk[1024];
   ssize_t ret = 0, n;
   while((n = ::read(fd, chunk, sizeof chunk)) > 0){
      ret += n;
      cerr << "read chunk: " << n << " | ";
      cerr.write(chunk, n);
      cerr << endl;
   }
   if (n < 0) {
       cerr << "err in read" << endl;
   }
   else if (ret == 0){
      cerr << "nothing to read" << endl;
   }
   return ret;
}

int main() {
   int bininfd = open("bin-in", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);//, 0644/*S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH*/);
   if (bininfd < 0) {
      perror("err in open(binin)");
      return -1;
   }

   struct pollfd pollfds[] = {
         {bininfd, POLLIN, 0},
   };
   auto&[pfd] = pollfds;

   while (1) {
      pfd.revents = 0;  // cleanup, shouldn't it be redundant
      int pollret = poll(pollfds, 1, -1);
      if (pollret > 0) {
         if (pfd.revents & POLLIN) {
            cerr << "(pfd.revents & POLLIN)" << endl;
            read_out_to_the_end(pfd.fd);
         }
      } else if (pollret == 0) {
         cerr << "poll timed out" << endl;
         continue;
      } else {
         cerr << "check for error" << endl;
         continue;
      }
   }
}
```

the output is

```
(pfd.revents & POLLIN)
nothing to read
(pfd.revents & POLLIN)
nothing to read
(pfd.revents & POLLIN)
nothing to read
(pfd.revents & POLLIN)
nothing to read
(pfd.revents & POLLIN)
............... etc ....................
```

[live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Rw-DX6)

UPDATE:

1. read_out_to_the_end() fixed. Thanks to @RemyLebeau
2. it works (blocks) on fifos as I expect, but not on regular files. Why?

Comment: Are you polling for writeable too?

Comment: why do you think it should wait?

Comment: After `poll()` exits, does `revents` contain any other flags besides `POLLIN`?  Specifically, does it include `POLLERR`, `POLLHUP`, or `POLLNVAL`?

Comment: A blocking read will return `EOF` immediately without having to wait for anything. Since a blocking read would not block, `poll()` should return that the file is ready to read. Do you want to wait for a file to change? If so, you should research how to do that (Hint: "file alteration monitoring"). These aren't the droids you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`poll()` or `select()` never block on regular files. They always return a regular file as "ready". If you want to use `poll()` to do what `tail -f` does, you're on the wrong track.

Quoting from the SUSv4 [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html):

> The `poll()` function shall support regular files, terminal and
>        pseudo-terminal devices, FIFOs, pipes, sockets and `[OB XSR]` STREAMS-based files. The behavior of `poll()` on
>        elements of fds that refer to other types of file is unspecified.
>
> **Regular files shall always poll TRUE for reading and writing**.

Since using `poll()` or `select()` on regular files is pretty much useless, newer interfaces have tried to remedy that. On BSD, you could use `kqueue(2)` with `EVFILT_READ`, and on Linux `inotify(2)` with `IN_MODIFY`. The newer `epoll(7)` interface on Linux will simply error out with `EPERM` if you try to watch a regular file.

Unfortunately, neither of those is standard.

Answer (score 1):

`read_out_to_the_end()` has several issues:

- `ret` is uninitialized.
- The `while` loop is incrementing `n` when it should be assigning it instead.  But then if the `while` loop hits the EOF, `if( n == 0)` will be true even if data was actually read before hitting EOF.
- `chunk` may be null-terminated, but it may also receive nulls too, depending on the input data. So it should not be written to `cerr` (why not `cout`?) using `operator<<`, use `cerr.write()` instead so that you can pass it the actual number of bytes read.

Try this instead:

```cpp
ssize_t read_out_to_the_end(int fd){
   char chunk[1024];
   ssize_t ret = 0, n;
   while((n = ::read(fd, chunk, sizeof chunk)) > 0){
      ret += n;
      cerr << "read chunk: " << n << " | ";
      cerr.write(chunk, n);
      cerr << endl;
   }
   if (n < 0) {
       cerr << "err in read" << endl;
   }
   else if (ret == 0){
      cerr << "nothing to read" << endl;
   }
   return ret;
}

int main() {
   int bininfd = open("bin-in", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);//, 0644/*S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH*/);
   if (bininfd < 0) {
      perror("err in open(binin)");
      return -1;
   }

   pollfd pfd = {};
   pfd.fd = bininfd;
   pfd.events = POLLIN;

   while (true) {
      pfd.revents = 0;  // cleanup, shouldn't it be redundant
      int pollret = poll(&pfd, 1, -1);
      if (pollret > 0) {
         if (pfd.revents & POLLIN) {
            cerr << "(pfd.revents & POLLIN)" << endl;
            read_out_to_the_end(pfd.fd);
         }
      } else if (pollret == 0) {
         cerr << "poll timed out" << endl;
         continue;
      } else {
         cerr << "poll error " << errno << endl;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Also, on a side note, the [`open()` documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) says:

> The `mode` argument specifies the file mode bits be applied when a new file is created.  **This argument must be supplied when O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE is specified in `flags`**; if neither O_CREAT nor O_TMPFILE is specified, then `mode` is ignored.  The effective mode is modified by the process's `umask` in the usual way: in the absence of a default ACL, the mode of the created file is `(mode & ~umask)`.  Note that this mode applies only to future accesses of the newly created file; the `open()` call that creates a read-only file may well return a read/write file descriptor.

Comment: Thank you. These mistakes have place but they are not critical in my case. poll() still does not block.

Comment: The only way that can happen is if `revents` has the `POLLIN` flag set, indicating the `fd` is in a readable state. Which then goes into making sure that `read_out_to_the_end()` is actually reading properly before returning to `poll()`. If it doesn't `read()` everything available then the `fd` will still be in a readable state. What kind of data is being written to `"bin-in"`, and when is it being written in relation to your program?

Comment: I expect to write binary data to "bin-in". For test purposes I would write to bin-in from shell with 'echo'.